# Format date of bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, date-formatting, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker on form with ajax to update date limit on the datepicker.

I hit the ajax to get total days and setEndDate of datepicker to limit upper date (all later dates will be disabled).

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if('total' in data && data['total'] > 1) {

            // datepicker successfully set the limit to next 'total' days
            $datepicker.datepicker('setEndDate', '+'+data['total']+'d');

            // how to set the field value with that end date?
            $datepicker.val($datepicker.datepicker('getEndDate'));
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

my question is how to format `$datepicker.datepicker('getEndDate')`, to `yyyy-mm-dd`?
currently it returns `Fri Jul 27 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)`.

I have check the documentation [1], but no parameter to assign on formatting the `getEndDate`.

appreciated any help.
thank you.

**edit:**

for anyone that having some problem with me,
currently my solution is parsing the return of `$datepicker.datepicker('getEndDate')` manually.

I saw the output was equal with Date `.toString()`, so I pass the output as JavaScript Date constructor then format it manually.

```
var d = new Date($datepicker.datepicker('getEndDate'));
if(d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d)) {
    var day = '' + d.getDate(),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    // console.log([year, month, day].join('-'));
    $datepicker.datepicker('update', [year, month, day].join('-'));
}
```

[1]http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("#date").data("datepicker").getFormattedDate()` but it gives the format of the selected date.

So you need to use the `getEndDate()` of the `datepicker` to get the end date and `DPGlobal` object to parse the date.

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
    format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
    endDate:"26/07/2018"
});

function getDate()
{
   var date = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate($("#date").data("datepicker").getEndDate(),"dd-mm-yyyy","en")
   console.log(date)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css"/>

<input id="date">
<button onclick="getDate()">Get Date</button>
```

Comment: where to find documentation about DPGlobal? I saw on bootstrap datepicker github, but can not find it on their documentation website, is it official tools (I mean will not deprecated anytime soon)?

Comment: I think it will not be deprecated. I verified their source. “getFormattedDate” internally uses it.